# How can I add data from User's Facebook to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've just moved from Parse to Firebase and not familiar with it's structure.

I'm developing a simple app with Facebook auth.

I understand how to add new authorized users to my database
[image]

Now I want to add additional data, that I get via Graph Request to this data, such as first name, last name, picture, gender etc

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class Settings: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var UserImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var UserName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var UserSurname: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Gender: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let paramets = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), gender"]

        let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: paramets)

        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({

            (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print (error)
            }

            if let first_name = result["first_name"] as? String {

                self.UserName.text = first_name

            }

            if let last_name = result["last_name"] as? String {

                self.UserSurname.text = last_name

            }

            if let picture = result["picture"] as? NSDictionary, data = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary, url = data["url"] as? String {

                print(url)

            }

            if let gender = result["gender"] as? String {

                self.Gender.text = gender

            }



        })
    }
```

What i need to do in order to add this data to my database? Should I create a new class, named Persons, for example, or I can use that one, I got from auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auth class is not designed to hold any of your data - It's read only and contains the auth credentials; uid etc.

You are off to a good start with your users node: that's a typical place you would store data about your users.

There are a number of ways to interact with Firebase - keeping in mind that there are no existing objects like there were in Parse. So, you can either just write data out to Firebase 'manually' or create a class to handle some of that for you.

So a simple example: Suppose a user created a firebase account and is then presented a dialog for the user to capture other info. You then want to store it in your /users node. Suppose you already have the firebase key (the authData.uid) so to add their name to that existing node...

```
let thisUserRef = usersRef.childByAppendingPath(uid)
let thisUserName = thisUserRef.childByAppendingPath("user_name")
let their_name = myUserNameTextField.StringValue
thisUserName.setValue(their_name)
```

results in:

```
uid_x
   user_name: "whatever their name is"
```

If you want to explore the space, build a dictionary and write out a bunch of children at the same time

```
let first_name = firstNameTextField.StringValue
let last_name = lastNameTextField.StringValue
let gender = myGenderTextField.StringValue
let user_info = ["first": first_name, "last": last_name, "gender": gender]
let thisUserRef = usersRef.childByAppendingPath(uid)
thisUserRef.setValue(user_info)
```

results in

```
uid_x
 first: "the first name"
 gender: "gender"
 last:  "the last name"
```

Now, if you want to get really snappy, create a class to handle the heavy lifting for you. Here's a PostClass that can be used to handle Posts.

```
import Cocoa
import Firebase

class PostClass: NSObject {

var firebaseKey : String?
var postText: String?
var uid: String?

func savePost() {

    let rootRef = Firebase(url:"https://your-app.firebaseio.com")
    let postsRef = rootRef.childByAppendingPath("posts")

    var dataDict = [String:String]()
    dataDict["msg"] = self.postText
    dataDict["uid"] = self.uid

    if firebaseKey != nil {
        let thisPostRef = postsRef.childByAppendingPath(firebaseKey)
        thisPostRef.updateChildValues(dataDict)
        //update existing node
    } else {
        //create new node
        let thisPostRef = postsRef.childByAutoId()
        thisPostRef.setValue(dataDict)
    }
}
```

and then to either create a new post or update an existing one, it's very object like:

```
    let aPost = PostClass()
    aPost.postText = "Some post"
    aPost.uid = "my user id"
    aPost.savePost()
```